# Wordpress, AJAX Call from localhost to a live site

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a local app (nodejs) that preprocesses data for my live web site (wordpress). I try to automatically pass the data via AJAX and I am getting a 403 access denied response.

What I want to know if this is a feasible idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, Just needed some headers.